# Improving folium map speed

Tags: python, folium

I made a map with some clusters and added a layer of polygon layer to the map, this consists of over 1 million rows, and the map became slow. Are the any way to speed it up when being used?

Answer (score 3):

As per [this](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1131) github closed issue, you can add `prefer_canvas=True` when you define the map. If that does not work, add it directly in the resulting HTML, as explained at the link.

Comment: I directly edited the html but it had zero impact on performance.  I have about 100K markers and it takes almost 3 minutes to load the page.